# Cant run Shell Script to launch Jar

Tags: java, shell, batch-file

i have a windows batch script which launches a jar which launches a game written all in Java (its a runescape client). It should work.

The original Batch (WIN):

```
@echo off
@echo Client Is loading......
@echo -----------------------
java -Xmx1000m -cp .;Theme.jar Gui 0 0 highmem members 32
pause
```

the Shell file ive made for OS:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Your client is loading...
echo --------------------
java -Xmx1000m -cp Theme.jar Gui 0 0 highmem members 32
```

the error in terminal:

```
Your Client is loading...
--------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Gui
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Gui
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

How can i fix it or make a shell script that will do the exact as the Batch and actually run?

Comment: Why are you including the current folder to the class path in your batch but not in your shell script? I speak of `-cp .;Theme.jar` in batch but `-cp Theme.jar` in shell file.

Comment: well if i do, i get this error http://pastie.org/8918011 (its too long to post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't convert the shell script correctly. In the Windows version the `-cp` parameter is `.;Theme.jar`, so in Linux it should be `.:Theme.jar`, the path separator `;` replaced with `:`, like this:

```
java -Xmx1000m -cp .:Theme.jar Gui 0 0 highmem members 32
```

A `ClassNotFoundException` in general signals something wrong with the classpath. (The `-cp` parameter is a shortcut for `-classpath`).

Judging by the Windows script, `Gui` is a class name, and the rest are command line arguments passed to the `Gui` class. The error message tells you it cannot find the `Gui` class. It must be either in the current directory or the `theme.jar`. If it's not in any of them then this can't work.

Comment: @Nicco is there a `Gui.class` file in the directory where you are running this? Or if you do `jar tf Theme.jar | grep Gui.class` what do you get?

Comment: arent Gui 0 0 highmem members 32 just variables?
I didnt write the original Batch, i only know it works on Windows..

How shall i include your solution?

Comment: @Nicco Judging by the Windows script, Gui is a class name, and the rest are command line arguments passed to the `Gui` class. The error message tells you it cannot find the `Gui` class. It must be either in the current directory or the `theme.jar`. If it's not in any of them then this can't work. You didn't answer my questions in my previous comment.

Comment: i got this btw  pastie.org/8918043 its only half due to copy limits

Comment: @Nicco this can't be the output of what I asked. I repeat: is there a `Gui.class` file in the directory where you are running this? Or if you do `jar tf Theme.jar | grep Gui.class` what do you get?

Comment: oops, 

this is what i get:

    java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:88)
     at sun.tools.jar.Main.list(Main.java:979)
     at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:224)
     at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1149)

Comment: @Nicco in that case your `theme.jar` looks broken. Try to copy again. Compare the file sizes in Windows and Linux, should be exactly the same.

Comment: theyre the exact same size: 1.7mb(1777876 bytes)

Comment: @Nicco you must be doing something wrong in OSX. Something you're overlooking and not mentioning. If the filesize is precisely the same in both systems, precisely 1777876 bytes, then the copy looks good. But then `jar tf Theme.jar` should not give you the `ZipException`. Maybe you're in the wrong folder. If the file is a valid jar, then `jar tf` will give you the list of files in it. Otherwise it's a corrupted file, unusable.

Comment: nonetheless it  cant be corrupted, i took the file back from OS and put it on Windows, works fine. Maybe it just cant be opened on here :/  ah well

Comment: I have found where Gui.Class is, it is in the same folder that the run script and Jar is in. . I dont see anything wrong though.. 
Gui.class: http://pastie.org/8918489  
Gui.java: http://pastie.org/8918486

Comment: the error im getting now is: Unable to access Theme.jar

Comment: @Nicco stupid question, but is `Theme.jar` file readable by your user?  Check the output of `ls -l Theme.jar`

Comment: well it should be.. Again, it does work on Win, and i am admin(if thats what u mean.)

heres what i got: ls: Theme.jar: No such file or directory

so im guessing no?
this guy was trying to do the same thing to the same file.. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2035844

Comment: still no closer to solving this issue :/ ive seen lots of counts of others having the issue now.. with the same file..

Comment: @Nicco, if `ls -l` tells you the file is not there, it's not there. You seem to be in the wrong directory. When `ls -l Theme.jar` and `jar tf Theme.jar` work, only then the program can work. Keep in mind that filenames are case sensitive, so `Theme.jar` is NOT the same as `theme.jar`

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

I think there might be two reason:

1. The jar file which you are including while running the java program is not included into the jar file which you have created for shell script.
2. You have not defined Main-Class in manifest.mf file while you created your jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this,

```
java -Xmx1000m -cp .: Theme.jar Gui 0 0 highmem members 32
```

as ':' is the classpath seperator for Unix environments while ';' is for Windows.

Comment: Try putting no space between .: and Theme.jar, I mean try using .:Theme.jar

Comment: @Nicco maybe because of the accidental space character in there after `:`. Make sure there is no space in `.:Theme.jar`.

Comment: yeah, i did remove that :( still didnt work and orig error. This is weird

Comment: on windows do this `java -verbose -Xmx1000m -cp Theme.jar Gui 0 0 highmem members 32`  this will print all classes being loaded and the src class (if file is not in jars) or jar file names. maybe you have not copied something from windows to linux/iOs. also run chmod 777 * on the dir in linux so all users can load all files.

Comment: Try this, java -Xmx1000m -cp Theme.jar:./ Gui 0 0 highmem members 32

Comment: all the files are definitely there.

Comment: @tgkprog `chmod 777` is unnecessary and dangerous. People mindlessly do `chmod 777` whenever they are lazy to understand what permissions they really need, and it's the source of many evils. Stop spreading this terrible habit.

Comment: Aditya,

java -Xmx1000m -cp Theme.jar:./ Gui 0 0 highmem members 32

 did not work. same error

Comment: if nothing else learn the process -  make a small hello worrld app, pack it to a jar, delete the class files outside or run jar from a new dir on linux/ iOS. use the -verbose command on this jar, compare it to the one you get on windows and on iOS with other app and will find the issue.

Comment: ok i tried that, It gave me lots of stuff so i could only copy half due to paste limits http://pastie.org/8918043